# Vuejs: How to edit name and insert icon in b-form-file

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm doing vuejs frontend. And now I'm getting to the file uploading part. I use `<b-form-file>` :

```html
<b-form-group>
  <b-form-file
    placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
    drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
  />
</b-form-group>
```

[image]

Now I want to change the name `Browse` to `Upload` and want to insert an icon in it.
The work I did was to put `name` and `label` and `icon` inside `b-form-file` but it still won't change the name and insert the icon :

```html
<b-form-group>
  <b-form-file
    placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
    drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
    name="Upload" // or label
    label="Upload"
    icon="download"
  />
</b-form-group>
```

Is there a way to modify `name` and insert `icon` inside `b-form-file` ? I can tweak the CSS to change it but it's not really good to do so. Please help me how to handle this case. Thanks.

Comment: So, using [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Customize File Input

###### Change default labels and design

[`b-form-file` Properties](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-file#comp-ref-b-form-file-props) - Bootstrap-Vue Docs
[`b-form-group` Properties](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-group#comp-ref-b-form-group-props) - Bootstrap-Vue Docs

Can change text of button with `browse-text` property on `b-form-file`.

```html
<b-form-group label-cols-sm="2">
  <b-form-file id="file-default" browse-text="Your Browse Here"></b-form-file> <!-- HERE -->
</b-form-group>
```

Can change text of label with `label` property on `b-form-group`.

```html
<b-form-group label="Your Label Here" label-cols-sm="2"> <!-- HERE -->
  <b-form-file id="file-default"></b-form-file>
</b-form-group>
```

###### Prepend, Append content (icons, etc.)

[`b-input-group` Properties](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/input-group) - Bootstrap-Vue Docs

Can use `template #prepend` and `template #append`

```html
<b-input-group>
  <template #prepend>
    <b-input-group-text>Your Content before input</b-input-group-text>
  </template>
  <b-form-input></b-form-input>
  <template #append>
    <b-input-group-text>Your Content after input</b-input-group-text>
  </template>
</b-input-group>
```

#### Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      file: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
  integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<link
  type="text/css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"
/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-group label="Your Label Here" label-cols-sm="2">
    <b-input-group>
      <template #prepend>
        <b-input-group-text><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i></b-input-group-text>
      </template>
      <b-form-file id="file-default" browse-text="Your Browse Here"></b-form-file>
    </b-input-group>
  </b-form-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped with my work. Can you tell me more. If you want to add an icon to `b-form-file`, how do you do it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You were looking for the `<b-input-group>` where you can insert multiple custom contents before and after the input field. I have also updated the example code.